# Meteor client synchronous server database calls

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

I am building an application in Meteor that relies on real time updates from the database. The way Meteor has laid out the examples is to have the database call under the Template call. I've found that when dealing with medium sized datasets this becomes impractical. I am trying to move the request to the server, and have the results passed back to the client.

I have looked at [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10274679/invoke-a-client-js-function-in-meteor-after-getting-results-from-the-server) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13368456/meteor-callfunction-arg-not-occurring-synchronously) on SA but have found no immediate answers.

Here is my server side function:

```
    Meteor.methods({
    "getTest" : function() {
                   var res = Data.find({}, { sort : { time : -1 }, limit : 10 });
                   var r = res.fetch();
                   return (r);
                }
    });
```

And client side:

```
    Template.matches._matches = function() {
        var res= {};
        Meteor.call("getTest", function (error, result) {
            res = result;
        });
        return res;
    }
```

I have tried variations of the above code - returning in the callback function as one example. As far as I can tell, having a callback makes the function asynchronous, so it cannot be called onload (synchronously) and has to be invoked from the client.

I would like to pass all database queries server side to lighten the front end load. Is this possible in Meteor?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to do this is to use subscriptions instead of remote method calls. See the [`counts-by-room` example](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_publish) in the docs. So, for every database call you have a collection that exists client-side only. The server then decides the records in the collection using `set` and `unset`.

Comment: I have already split data into collections, wouldn't doing this: console.log("Current room has " + Counts.findOne().count + " messages."); still put the load on client side? As far as I can tell this is the same thing as I am doing currently, which I want to get away from.

Comment: It does indeed do a call to the local database, but the Counts collection contains only one row, so it is very quick. Using client-side collections is only slow when all the data is at the client. Limiting what data is at the client with `Meteor.publish` fixes that.

Comment: I see. So I will attempt to solve this by having a collection for every query (per page) I wish to run. Sounds like it will work just fine though. Thanks!